# PHP Function efficiency issue

Tags: php, performance

The purpose of the code below is checking 2 parameters the day and the time AM or PM. My code works but i am trying to make if more efficient and need help please. I have 2 if statement for the day for example this if statement sun pm and sun am, then I have mon tues, wed, thur...... so this is pretty long. I was told that there was a way to make it shorter please help.

```
if ($day == 'Sun' && $AMorPM == 'pm')
{
echo"
<fieldset>
<Legend><b>CHECK-OUT</b></Legend>
Date out:<input name='DateOut' type='text' value=$dateout disabled='disabled'><br>
Time out:<input name='TimeOut' type='text' value=$timeout disabled='disabled'> 
<input type='radio' name='AM'disabled='disabled'>AM 
<input type='radio' name='PM' checked disabled='disabled'>PM<br>
Day of week: <input type='radio' name='S'checked disabled='disabled'>S 
<input type='radio' name='Mon' disabled='disabled'>M 
<input type='radio' name='Tue'disabled='disabled'>T 
<input type='radio' name='Wed'disabled='disabled'>W 
<input type='radio' name='Thu'disabled='disabled'>R 
<input type='radio' name='Fri'disabled='disabled'>F 
<input type='radio' name='Sat'disabled='disabled'>S
</fieldset>";
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to make code that consists of a single `echo` even more efficient. So you either ask about efficiency, or about its length.

Comment: @zerkms I don't think he's looking for performance benefits.  He has a bunch of am/pm day-of-week combos and is looking for the best way to deal with them.

Comment: @Levi Morrison: I don't think as well, but the "efficiency" word was used. The question needs to be rephrased. "the best way to deal with them" is barely an "efficiency"

Comment: well you can talk about efficiency in terms of length/maintainability/readability of code or in terms of speed of execution.

Answer (score 0):

Do you do the same thing for AM vs. PM regardless of the day of the week?  Do you do the same thing for every day of the week regardless of the time of day?  If so, then why don't you deal with the AM/PM bit first and the day of the week separately?

```
echo "<fieldset>
    <Legend><b>CHECK-OUT</b></Legend>
    Date out:<input name='DateOut' type='text' value=$dateout disabled='disabled'><br>
    Time out:<input name='TimeOut' type='text' value=$timeout disabled='disabled'> 
    <input type='radio' name='AM'";

if ($AMorPM == "am")
   echo " checked ";

echo "disabled='disabled'>AM <input type='radio' name='PM'";

if ($AMorPM == "pm")
    echo " checked ";

echo " disabled='disabled'>PM<br>";
```

That code will do what you want for the time of day, regardless of what day of the week is selected.  Now do the same thing for each day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

You could set it up as a function -

```
//create array of days/short day codes
$day_array = array('Sun'=>'S', 'Mon'=>'M', 'Tue'=>'T', 'Wed'=>'W', 'Thu'=>'R', 'Fri'=>'F', 'Sat'=>'S');

//creates clock function
function clock($today, $ampm, $date, $time, $dayarray){

if ($ampm == 'am') {$punch_type =  "CHECK-IN";
                   $inout = 'in'; 
                   $inout_up = ucfirst($inout);
                   $checked_am = 'checked = "checked"';
} 
else               {$punch_type = "CHECK-OUT";
                   $inout = 'out'; 
                   $inout_up = ucfirst($inout);
                   $checked_pm = 'checked = "checked"';
}
//sets day of the week array vars, based of today
$dayof_week = $dayarray[$today];

echo"
<fieldset>
<Legend><b>$punch_type</b></Legend>
Date $inout:<input name='Date$inout_up' type='text' value=$date disabled='disabled'><br>
Time $inout:<input name='Time$inout_up' type='text' value=$time disabled='disabled'> 
<input type='radio' name='AM' $checked_am disabled='disabled'>AM <input type='radio' name='PM' $checked_pm disabled='disabled'>PM<br>
Day of week: ";

// loop through day array to create radios for every day of the week
foreach($dayarray as $key=>$value){
    // sets which day is checked
    $chkd = ($today == $key) ? ' checked = "checked"' : ''; 
    // creates each radio
    echo "<input type='radio' name='$key' $chkd disabled='disabled'>$value";}

echo"</fieldset>";
}
```

Then you can call the function by doing -

```
clock("Sun", "am", "8/28/12", "10:30", $day_array);
```

This way, you don't need to rewrite the script for every day. If you just dynamically set the 4 variables in the function, it will dynamically build/display your clock
ie.

```
clock($day, $AMorPM, $date, $time, $day_array);
```